# How to reduce repetition in JSON stubbed data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out some techniques preferably using ES6 (but not required) to reduce the repetition here in my stub data. I was told there's a way I could make it cleaner (less repetitive) but I don't see it yet.

```
countries = [{id: 1, name:"France"},
                {id: 2, name:"Germany"},
                {id: 3, name:"United Kingdom"},
                {id: 4, name:"Canada"},
                {id: 5, name:"Poland"},
                {id: 6, name:"Spain"}];
```

This is in one of my unit tests.

Comment: "cleaner" is a very subjective term and will need explanation if you wish an answer to address it.  "less repetitive" is unclear to me.  The only repetitive things I see are the object property names, which by the way are not, strictly speaking, valid JSON, though many JSON parsers will be fine with it.

Comment: "less repetition" of the --field names-- and less repetition of {} there's gotta be a way to reduce some of that repetition. Condense.  having multiple id:  and name: 6 times in a row is duplication.

Comment: use an array to create a json dynamically, you will have to write a function for it.

Comment: reducing that kind of repetition is not always a good thing.  "creative" solutions are typically not easy to see whats going on at a glance - maintenance costs are increased.

Comment: reducing repetition in code is always a good thing.  It's good for your tests and it's good for your prod code.  Don't talk to me about costs.  I TDD, I won't agree with you.  This is not tricky, what I'm asking to do, it shouldn't be something that's very extravagant to do.  I just can't think of a way.  Reducing repetition often is one of the core tenants of TDD.  And critical.

Comment: What do you do when your are paginating the results and get id's 6 - 12?. I would personally keep it the same as the abstractions are just adding to complication that is not necessary. or just index an Object with the country name, then you can have no duplication and you get easy access to the country.

Comment: this is for a unit test.  I guess I'm not understanding what you're point is @synthet1c.  Can you describe more...

Comment: sorry missed that info. I still wouldn't use the abstraction though ;-). `getCountries = () => ([ { id: 1, name: "France" }, ... ])` just create a reusable factory to return you the object you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to reduce repetition.

```
var countries = ["France", "Germany", 
                 "United Kingdom", "Canada", 
                 "Poland", "Spain"]
                   .map((x, idx) => ({id: idx+1, name: x}));
```

With underscore or lodash:

```
var countries = _.map(["France", "Germany", 
                 "United Kingdom", "Canada", 
                 "Poland", "Spain"], (val, idx) =>
                  ({ id: idx+1,  name: val }));
```

Comment: instead of keeping an external variable `i`, can we somehow use array's index itself !

Comment: Thanks! I added an example using lodash/underscore `_.map`

Comment: You don't need to have the `i` variable, you can just use the second argument of the map callback which is the current iteration. `(x, i) => ({ id: i+1, name: x })`

Comment: since you came up with the idea to use map first, if you change your code to use arrow functions like Weedoze did I'll accept this as the answer...unless someone else has another idea.

Comment: Nice!  I guess I just didn't think of using map this way, exactly the kind of thing I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `Array#map()`

```js
let a =["France","Germany","United Kingdom","Canada","Poland","Spain"].map((c,i)=>({id:++i,name:c}));

console.log(a);
```

Comment: that's more like it

Comment: how are you adding the run code snippet functionality into a stack post?

Comment: @PositiveGuy Look in the bar with italic, bold,... there is `<>` click on it